# SQLite, Multiply table select with table identification

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to print table name in result, and how if it is...
in example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2;
```

I'll get this result:

```
1 | 2 | 3

4 | 5 | 6
```

where the first row is from `table1` and the second row from `table2`, but I want those table-names to be included in the output, like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | TABLE1

4 | 5 | 6 | TABLE2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I just need to put the table-name as a string literal in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    *,
    'TABLE1' AS "name"
FROM
    TABLE1

UNION

SELECT
    *,
    'TABLE2' AS "name"
FROM
    TABLE2;
```